# Move silverlight dynamic animation to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have silverlight animation (workig for 100% sure):

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform/>
</UserControl.RenderTransform>
```

and in code:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));
```

I tried in WPF this:

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform />
</UserControl.RenderTransform>
```

and:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));
```

but it crashes with exception that path (UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X) cannot be resolved or sth like this.. Can you help?

Comment: I don't think this'd make a difference, but can you try replacing "UIElement" with "UserControl" in your PropertyPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

code-behind:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)"));
```

markup:

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </TransformGroup>
</UserControl.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer why it crashes. From what I see, it really shouldn't be crashing, as the OPs current method looks fine to me.

Comment: well, it started to working after this change, it looks like adding children was the key

Answer (score 1):

As you probably figured out there is no CompositeTransform in WPF.  The standard way to create Transforms is to create a TransformGroup. Then add the four types of transforms.

```
<UserControl.RenderTransform> 
<TransformGroup> 
    <TranslateTransform /> 
    <ScaleTransform />
    <SkewTransform />
    <RotateTransform />
</TransformGroup>
```

Then the animatation refers to the transform using indexer syntax.

```
(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)
```

Comment: the example at the end of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx is also helpful (shows how to use either a TransformGroup or a CompositeTransform in your XAML)